# How can I always terminate a NodeJs script with a timeout even if the event loop is occupied?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

Is it possible to use **setTimeout** in NodeJS to terminate a process even if the event loop is being occupied by something else?

For example, say I have code that looks like the following

```
setTimeout(async () => {
    // Some code I run to gracefully exit my process.
}, timeout);

while (true) {
    let r = 1;
}
```

The callback in my timeout will never be hit since the while loop will occupy the event loop. Is there some way that I can say: "Execute the following code after **N** seconds regardless of everything else?"

I'm writing selenium tests, but for some reason every once in a while the test will get "stuck" and never terminate. I basically want to always timeout my tests after a certain amount of time so we don't get into the position of tests that run forever.

Thanks!

Comment: I run process.exit() as part of the "// Some code I run to gracefully exit my process" :)

The issue is that I want to run that after a certain amount of time has passed, which is where the difficult in using setTimeout comes in.

Comment: Totally! That's what I'm doing currently. The issue is that the setTimeout callback is never run because the event loop is occupied by some synchronous code that never terminates. In the example I gave above, the callabk isn't run because the infinite while loop never gives back control.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since JavaScript is single threaded, what you are going to want to do is to create a worker using [fork](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options), which will give it the feeling of being multi threaded. This will actually just give us two instances of node, each one having their own event loop. This fork will have your endless loop which you can then kill with your timeout.

**main.js**

```
const cp = require('child_process')
const path = require('path')

// Create the child
const child = cp.fork(path.join(__dirname, './worker.js'), [])

// Kill after "x" milliseconds
setTimeout(() => {
  process.exit()
}, 5000);

// Listen for messages from the child
child.on('message', data => console.log(data))
```

Next you will setup your worker:

**worker.js**

```
let i = 0;
while (true) {
  // Send the value of "i" to the parent
  process.send(i++);
}
```

The child can communicate info about itself to the parent using `process.send(data)`.

The parent can listen for messages from the child using `child.on('message', ...)`.

---

Another thing we can do is kill the child instead of the main process if you need the main process to do more stuff still. And in this case you would call `child.kill()` inside the `setTimeout` instead.

```
const cp = require('child_process')
const path = require('path')

// Create the child
let child = cp.fork(path.join(__dirname, './worker.js'), [])

// Kill after "x" milliseconds
setTimeout(() => {
  child.kill()
}, 5000);
```

If there are no more events in the eventloop, the main process will automatically close itself thus we don't need to call `process.exit()`.